# Why is TaskCanceledException thrown when using Dapper QueryAsync<T> without async/await?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, dapper

Why does calling `.Result` on this method result in a TaskCanceledException:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetAsync()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        return conn.QueryAsync<object>("select * from objects");
    }
}
```

But calling `.Result` on this method works:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetAsync()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
    {
        return await conn.QueryAsync<object>("select * from objects");
    }
}
```

The difference being the `async\await` keywords are being used in the second method.

Answer (score 8):

The first method starts the query (calls `QueryAsync`), then it disposes the `SqlConnection`, and then it returns the task representing that query. The task is canceled because the `SqlConnection` was disposed before it could complete.

The second method starts the query (calls `QueryAsync`), asynchronously waits for that query to complete, and *then* disposes the `SqlConnection`. The task returned from the second method represents the completion of that method.

For more information on `async`/`await`, see [my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

On a side note, you should not consume asynchronous methods with `Result`; you should use `await` instead.

Comment: I realize `Result` is generally the wrong way to consume async methods; particularly when the SynchronizationContext is not null. But in this case it was null because I ran into this situation while doing some ad hoc testing in a unit test proj and just wanted to see quick results, which I consider to be a valid use of `Result`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason the first method throws an exception is because the SqlConnection object is going out of scope when the Task is returned from the method.

The reason the second method works is because the async & await keywords simulate a closure due to the compiler wrapping the method in a state-machine-like struct behind the scenes. This ends up keeping the `SqlConnection` in scope. I won't go much further than that because the details are a bit complex and vary based on the compiler.

To make it possible to return a Task without the async/await keywords you'd need to pass in the SqlConnection so it remains in scope upon returning the Task:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetAsync(SqlConnection conn)
{
    return conn.QueryAsync<object>("select * from objects");
}
```

#### Update #1 (in response to comment)

Why it has to do with scope and closures:

Instantiating the `SqlConnection` in the `using` statement limits its **scope** to the `using` block. So when the first method leaves the `using` block and returns the Task, the `SqlConnection` goes out of scope and gets disposed prior to the Task completing. In the second method, the `async/await` keywords will cause the compiler to create a `struct` behind the scenes and it will store the async method's local variables as fields in that struct so they can be used in the callback (code below the await) when the Task completes. This is similar to how **[closures](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained)** are implemented behind the scenes.

Comment: No, the difference in behavior does not have anything to do with scopes or closure-like objects.

Comment: @StephenCleary yes, it does. see update #1. it seems like your answer is saying the same thing but one level higher.

Comment: I think we're disagreeing on the definition of "scope" here. For both methods, the scope of the `SqlConnection` is the same: it's only within the `using` block.

Comment: I agree with your statement on the scope of `SqlConnection`. I think we're just working on different levels of abstraction here. When the method using `async/await` gets compiled, the using block will actually go away and the internal struct will have a field referencing the `SqlConnection`, which it will call `Dispose()` on after running the callback. I guess my objective was to explain _how_ the `SqlConnection` was remaining in scope behind the scenes when using `async/await`.